# Cannot post Json array to web core api

Tags: c#, arrays, json, ajax, asp.net-core-webapi

With this code I am trying to post a Json array to a method in my web core API. However the array arrives as null.

```
importProperties = function (url, callback, data) {
        var properties = JSON.stringify(data);
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { "": properties }
        })
            .done(callback)
            .fail(errorMessage);
    }
```

Once the data is JSON.stringified, it looks like;

```
[{"UPRN":"12345","StreetName":"COMPORT GREEN","AddressLine2":"NEW ADDINGTON","AddressLine3":"Croydon","AddressLine4":"Surrey","Postcode":"CR0 0BY","Latitude":null,"Longitude":null,"BlockUPRN":"B12345","PropertyNo":"1","BlockName":"Block Court","Comments":null,"PropertyTypeId":6,"NumberOfBathrooms":1,"NumberOfBedrooms":2,"NumberOfKitchens":1,"PropertyContractId":0,"PropertyType":null},
{"UPRN":"67890","StreetName":"COMPORT GREEN","AddressLine2":"NEW ADDINGTON","AddressLine3":"Croydon","AddressLine4":"Surrey","Postcode":"CR0 0BY","Latitude":null,"Longitude":null,"BlockUPRN":"B67890","PropertyNo":"2","BlockName":"Block Court","Comments":null,"PropertyTypeId":6,"NumberOfBathrooms":null,"NumberOfBedrooms":null,"NumberOfKitchens":null,"PropertyContractId":0,"PropertyType":null}]
```

The method signature on my web core API is;

```
[HttpPost("{contractId}/import")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Import(int contractId, [FromBody] IEnumerable<PropertyAndContractDto> properties)
{
   this.NLogger.Info($"api/property/contractId = {contractId}/saveproperties".ToPrefix());
   if (properties == null)
   {
      return BadRequest();
   }
...
}
```

The DTO is

```
    public class PropertyAndContractDto
    {
        public string UPRN { get; set; }
        public string StreetName { get; set; }
        public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
        public string AddressLine3 { get; set; }
        public string AddressLine4 { get; set; }
        public string Postcode { get; set; }
        public string Latitude { get; set; }
        public string Longitude { get; set; }
        public string BlockUPRN { get; set; }
        public string PropertyNo { get; set; }
        public string BlockName { get; set; }
        public string Comments { get; set; }
        public int? PropertyTypeId { get; set; }
        public int? NumberOfBathrooms { get; set; }
        public int? NumberOfBedrooms { get; set; }
        public int? NumberOfKitchens { get; set; }
        public int PropertyContractId { get; set; }
        public string PropertyType { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When I run in Postman it works;

[image]

So why is the properties parameter coming in as null?

Comment: Most likely because it can't be parsed into `PropertyAndContractDto`. Post the DTO class. Are the class properties the same as those in the string? *Can* you parse this string into an array of DTO's to begin with?

Comment: Mhh I guess the Model binding doesnt work. You need a class with a property of type `IEnumerable<PropertyAndContractDto>`. But not 100% sure.

Comment: I have posted the Dto. It is the same class for both the web core api and the data.

Comment: Did you try changing `data: { "": properties }` to `data: { "properties": properties }`?

Comment: @Sebastian - tried that but I got the same outcome

Comment: @Siva - yes but no difference. That was what I tried originally.

Comment: Try with `data: { "PropertyAndContractDto": properties }`. Also did you check if the data/array going in URL or body since you have annotated with `[FromBody]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the `processData` property of the ajax call to false, like this:

```
$.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { "": properties },
            processData: false
        })
```

According to the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax):

> By default, data passed in to the data option as an object
>   (technically, anything other than a string) will be processed and
>   transformed into a query string, fitting to the default content-type
>   "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". If you want to send a
>   DOMDocument, or other non-processed data, set this option to false.

Alternatively, just set the `data` property to your stringified json:

```
$.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            data: properties
        })
```

Comment: Your second suggestion was the answer. I thought I tried every alternative but after a number of corrections I did not revert back to this one. So thank you for that.